# Merging xts objects with some common columns

Tags: r, merge, time-series, xts

I am back-testing a trading strategy on the members of a stock index. I have historical stock price date for every years. I would like to merge these time-series objects. My problem is that the index constituents are not the same , therefore I could not simple rbind them. Merging is not an option as well, because it creates separate columns for the same stocks from different years. Could someone suggest me a solution?

Here is an example of my problem:
xts1:

```
                                  AAPL    AMZ   AA    AXP     
              11/01/2020          100     85     90    70     
              12/01/2020          105     70     80    90
```

xts2:

```
                                  AAPL    AM    AXP     BA
              01/01/2021          108     75     80     50
              02/01/2021          110     60     70     60
```

final xts:

```
                                  AAPL    AMZ   AA    AXP     BA
              11/01/2020          100     85     90    70     NA
              12/01/2020          105     70     80    90     NA
              01/01/2021          108     75     NA    80     50
              02/01/2021          110     60     NA    70     60
```

Comment: Your output shows like `rbind` i.e. try `bind_rows(fortify.zoo(xt1), fortify.zoo(xt2))`

Comment: Do you have 'AM' or 'AMZ' in the second data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `order.by` i.e. index of `xts` should be Date/Datetime class.  According to `?xts

> order.by - a corresponding vector of unique times/dates - must be of a known time-based class.

If the initial objects are `xts` and the dates are `Date` class, an option is to `rbind` after converting to `data.frame` with `fortify.zoo`

```
library(xts)
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(fortify.zoo(xt1), fortify.zoo(xt2))
       Index AAPL AMZ AA AXP BA
1 2020-11-01  100  85 90  70 NA
2 2020-12-01  105  70 80  90 NA
3 2021-01-01  108  75 NA  80 50
4 2021-02-01  110  60 NA  70 60
```

---

If we want to reconvert to `xts`

```
out <- bind_rows(fortify.zoo(xt1), fortify.zoo(xt2))
xts(out[-1], order.by = out$Index)
           AAPL AMZ AA AXP BA
2020-11-01  100  85 90  70 NA
2020-12-01  105  70 80  90 NA
2021-01-01  108  75 NA  80 50
2021-02-01  110  60 NA  70 60
```

#### data

```
xt1 <- structure(c(100L, 105L, 85L, 70L, 90L, 80L, 70L, 90L), .Dim = c(2L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("AAPL", "AMZ", "AA", "AXP")), index = structure(c(1604188800, 
1606780800), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"))

xt2 <- structure(c(108L, 110L, 75L, 60L, 80L, 70L, 50L, 60L), .Dim = c(2L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("AAPL", "AMZ", "AXP", "BA")), index = structure(c(1609459200, 
1612137600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We define a function `Merge` that merges two xts objects.  It only uses the xts package.  It uses `c.xts` and `cbind.xts` to carry this out.

The `xts1` and `xts2` objects used in the example below are shown in reproducible form in the Note at the end.

```
Merge <- function(xts1, xts2) {

  nms1 <- names(xts1)
  nms2 <- names(xts2)
  both <- intersect(nms1, nms2)

  cbind(c(xts1[, both], xts2[, both]), 
        xts1[, !nms1 %in% both], 
        xts2[, !nms2 %in% both])
}

x <- Merge(xts1, xts2); x
```

giving this xts object:

```
           AAPL AXP AMZ AA AM BA
2020-11-01  100  70  85 90 NA NA
2020-12-01  105  90  70 80 NA NA
2021-01-01  108  80  NA NA 75 50
2021-02-01  110  70  NA NA 60 60
```

Also note that xts supports yearmon class which represents a year and month internally as year + fraction where the fraction is 0 for Jan, 1/12 for Feb, ..., 11/12 for Dec and it displays as shown below.

```
aggregate(x, as.yearmon)
```

giving:

```
         AAPL AXP AMZ AA AM BA
Nov 2020  100  70  85 90 NA NA
Dec 2020  105  90  70 80 NA NA
Jan 2021  108  80  NA NA 75 50
Feb 2021  110  70  NA NA 60 60
```

### Note

```
library(xts)

Lines1 <- "                      AAPL    AMZ   AA    AXP     
              11/01/2020          100     85     90    70     
              12/01/2020          105     70     80    90     "
xts1 <- read.zoo(text = Lines1, format = "%m/%d/%Y", index = 0) |>
  as.xts()

Lines2 <- "                                  AAPL    AM    AXP     BA
              01/01/2021          108     75     80     50
              02/01/2021          110     60     70     60 " 
xts2 <- read.zoo(text = Lines2, format = "%m/%d/%Y", index = 0) |>
  as.xts()
```